# Creating a network in Python using XML data

Tags: python, xml

I have a .xml file over here
http://sndlib.zib.de/coredata.download.action?objectName=germany50&format=xml&objectType=network

And I'd like to read the attributes to create a network in Python. I could only succeed in reading the attributes and I'm clueless about how to proceed. I need to create a bi-directional network using the data in the .xml file. My python code looks like this. Could any of you please help me with this?

Thanks and Regards

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom as dom 
import string
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os
Read_Data = minidom.parse("germany50.xml")
nodelist = Read_Data.getElementsByTagName("node")
for node in nodelist :
    if node.hasAttribute("id"):
        Node = node.getAttribute("id")
    xCoordinates = node.getElementsByTagName('x') [0]
    yCoordinates = node.getElementsByTagName('y') [0]
    print "%s : %s %s" %(node.getAttribute("id"), xCoordinates.childNodes[0].data, yCoordinates.childNodes[0].data)

linklist = Read_Data.getElementsByTagName("link")
for link in linklist :
    if link.hasAttribute("id"):
        Link = link.getAttribute("id")
    Source = link.getElementsByTagName('source') [0]
    Destination = link.getElementsByTagName('target') [0]
    Capacity = link.getElementsByTagName('capacity') [0]
    print "%s - %s to %s: %s" %(link.getAttribute("id"), Source.childNodes[0].data, Destination.childNodes[0].data, Capacity.childNodes[0].data)
demandlist = Read_Data.getElementsByTagName("demand")
for demand in demandlist :
    if demand.hasAttribute("id"):
        Demand = demand.getAttribute("id")
    Source = demand.getElementsByTagName('source') [0]
    Destination = demand.getElementsByTagName('target') [0]
    Demand = demand.getElementsByTagName('demandValue') [0]
    print "%s needs %s" %(demand.getAttribute("id"), Demand.childNodes[0].data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs to use the OOPS concept of Python to create a network. The code would look something like as shown below.
nodemap is the map with every node and nodes are internally linked to each other using links and demand.

```
import sys
import xml.dom.minidom as dom 
import string
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os
Read_Data = minidom.parse("germany50.xml")
nodelist = Read_Data.getElementsByTagName("node")

class Node:
    def __init__(self,uid,x,y):
        self.uid=uid
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.linklist=[]
        self.demandlist=[]

class Link:
    def __init__(self,uid,source,target,capacity):
        self.uid=uid
        self.source=source
        self.target=target
        self.capacity=capacity

class Demand:
    def __init__(self,uid,source,destination,demandValue):
        self.uid=uid
        self.source=source
        self.destination=destination
        self.demandValue=demandValue


nodemap={}

for node in nodelist :
    if node.hasAttribute("id"):
        Nodeid = node.getAttribute("id")
    xCoordinates = node.getElementsByTagName('x') [0]
    yCoordinates = node.getElementsByTagName('y') [0]
    nodemap[Nodeid]=Node(Nodeid,xCoordinates,yCoordinates)
    print "%s : %s %s" %(node.getAttribute("id"), xCoordinates.childNodes[0].data, yCoordinates.childNodes[0].data)

linklist = Read_Data.getElementsByTagName("link")
for link in linklist :
    if link.hasAttribute("id"):
        Linkid = link.getAttribute("id")
    Source = link.getElementsByTagName('source') [0]
    Destination = link.getElementsByTagName('target') [0]
    Capacity = link.getElementsByTagName('capacity') [0]
    linkobj= Link(Linkid,Source,Destination,Capacity)
    if nodemap.has_key(Source):
        nodemap[Source].linklist.append(linkobj)
    if nodemap.has_key(Destination):
        nodemap[Destination].linklist.append(linkobj)

    print "%s - %s to %s: %s" %(link.getAttribute("id"), Source.childNodes[0].data, Destination.childNodes[0].data, Capacity.childNodes[0].data)
demandlist = Read_Data.getElementsByTagName("demand")
for demand in demandlist :
    if demand.hasAttribute("id"):
        Demandid = demand.getAttribute("id")
    Source = demand.getElementsByTagName('source') [0]
    Destination = demand.getElementsByTagName('target') [0]
    Demandval = demand.getElementsByTagName('demandValue') [0]
    demandobj=Demand(Demandid,Source,Destination,Demandval)
    if nodemap.has_key(Source):
        nodemap[Source].demandlist.append(demandonj)
    if nodemap.has_key(Destination):
        nodemap[Destination].demandlist.append(demandobj)

    print "%s needs %s" %(demand.getAttribute("id"), Demandval.childNodes[0].data)




print nodemap
```

It would be advisable to go through the OOPS concepts in Python which would give you an idea as of how Networks, Graphs , Trees can be formed in Python.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. I am going to try it tomorrow and get back to you with more queries if you don't mind. 

Varun

Comment: I am game. Still I would recommend going through the Python Object Oriented concepts.

Comment: Hey, I really need your help this time. I'm not able to figure this thing out. Could you help me fix this problem? The link gives the files I'm working on. I kind of used your idea and proceeded. But when I try and generate this topology, it shows "list index out of range". I'm working on the export.py file currently and I'm trying to generate this topology as in the source xml file and then add a few more attributes to it and finally write this stuff onto another xml file. I'm sorry to be bothering you over and over. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8h321y7c9c60vt/AADzDj7oOM8YU76Ww6W4LIPYa

Comment: Please share the command you are running and the traceback of the error that you get.

Comment: python export.py --output topology.xml --xml germany50.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export.py", line 239, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "export.py", line 234, in main
    network.addEdge( PHY_LINKS( j , sourcen, destnn, sid, did, cap_bdw) )
  File "/home/srva/Approach_Read.py", line 89, in addEdge
    self.nodes[ edge.SourceID ].addInEdge( edge )
IndexError: list index out of range                I have messed up the program quite a lot because of the frustration :D

Answer (score 1):

```
for link in linklist :
    if link.hasAttribute("id"):
        Linkid = link.getAttribute("id")
    Source = link.getElementsByTagName('source') [0]
    Destination = link.getElementsByTagName('target') [0]
    Capacity = link.getElementsByTagName('capacity') [0]
    linkobj= Link(Linkid,Source,Destination,Capacity)
    if nodemap.has_key(Source):
        nodemap[Source].linklist.append(linkobj)
    if nodemap.has_key(Destination):
        nodemap[Destination].linklist.append(linkobj)
```

Please see you are missing the case where it can be a possibility where your nodes list might contain [A,B,C,D] and your links might contain [(A,C),(B,E)]. In this case, you have to create a node E first and then create a link. I noticed this case present in the given xml and above is provided the handling for it.

Comment: But when I try and adapt this to my problem, I see that I don't have nodemap={}. Instead I'm collecting these edges and nodes and then using them in the   `class PHY_NETWORK:
    def __init__(self, nodes, edges, nameToIdMap):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = edges  
        self.nameToIdMap = nameToIdMap`         I'm really bad at editing this one. Moreover the nodes contain a method addEdge. I'd like to retain that sort of a method. I'm sorry for the trouble

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I was busy with my own stuff. You should actually keep a check in addEdge function. Something like:
if not self.nodes[ edge.SourceID ]:
   CREATE A PHYNODE WITH SOURCEID
if not self.nodes[edge.DesinationID]:
   CREATE A PYHNODE WITH DESTINATIONID
and then the code you have already written.

In case, the links has some Node value not present in the Nodelist, we are creating a New node for it.
Hope this is clear to you now.I did not get the time to run your program, neither do I have the cplex installed on my system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My file seems to be working fine.You could take a look at it if you want. https://www.dropbox.com/s/952erbyc23msssm/topology3.xmla.xml   I wrote it in a different way and your comments really helped me.

Comment: Good to hear that! Cheers !!